# Xcode througing error in phonegap NSURLErrorDomain error

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova

i am new to phonegap with Angularjs. I am trying to figure out that why i am getting this issue:

```
2015-04-28 00:54:17.178 Come To Woodstock[25507:2562346] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2015-04-28 00:54:17.331 Come To Woodstock[25507:2562346] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

This is error i am getting when ever i am compiling the code with Xcode. Here is how my angular (javascript) file looks like:

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen', 'ngSanitize']);

module.controller('directoryControl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, ajaxCall) {
ons.ready(function() {

                $scope.spinner = true;
                var dataURL = "get_category_index";
                var valuePickup = "categories"
                ajaxCall.GetIndex($scope, dataURL, valuePickup);
                $scope.setCurrentCategory = function(categoryName){
                    $scope.CurrentCategory = categoryName;
                    $rootScope.CurrentCategory=$scope.CurrentCategory;
                }

          $scope.online = navigator.onLine;
          $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
                                   alert("Connection offline");
                                   }, false);
          $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
                                  alert("Connection Online");
                                   }, false);
    });
});

module.service('ajaxCall',function($http){
    var self = this; 
    var websiteURL = "http://www.somewebsite.com/api/";  
    self.GetIndex = function(scope, dataURL, valuePickup){
    $http.get(websiteURL + dataURL).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data[valuePickup]);
                scope.AllData = data[valuePickup];
                scope.spinner = false;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("ajax didnt work");
            });
        }
});

module.filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
    }
  }
);
module.filter('replaceDashFilter', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return String(text).replace(/-/g, ' ');
    }
  }
);
```

Do anyone else find the same issue earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Would need a little more than this to find out what's going on. Have you tried PhoneGap's debug docs? These console messages are vague, but there is quite a bit of information when running debug

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Also you can revert to desktop and see what errors you're getting there. Try to console.log some stuff. If else fails post some debug logs.

Comment: console.log is not giving any kind of error. I tried everything.

Comment: I remove all of my code and i guess this line is a problem somewhere "var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen', 'ngSanitize']);"

Comment: Could it be a dependency problem? does it work when you strip it down that far?

Comment: Yes if i remove the line then no error. I dont know much about Angular with phonegap i am new into this. So dont know what to do!